# Call a jar file function in VB6.0

Tags: function, jar, vb6, executable-jar

I have a jar file lets say a.jar and I have also a VB6.0 application called b.exe. So I want to use the functions of a.jar in the b.exe application. Please what would be the syntax to implement it. If you have any reference please share with me.

Can I call this jar file same as we call .dll files in vb6.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB cannot directly interact with Java. But it can talk to VC++. VC++ can talk to Java. You need to use JNI (Java Native Interface) for this. So, write VC++ DLL that interacts with java and let the VB invoke the VC++ DLL functions. Hundreds of examples are available on the net for JNI.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/